# Async class method returns Function instead AsyncFunction

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

@Edit: I have found a "solution". I have check the returns of method. This is not the ideal but solves my personal problem.
`console.log(name.setName().constructor.name === "Promise")`

Why this method is returning `Function` instead `AsyncFunction`

When I run this code on node, I get `AsyncFunction`, but when I run on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-surf-hgihj?file=/src/index.js) or my [react project](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-https-21q16), I get `Function` instead.

```
class Name {
  constructor(name) {
    this.myName = name;
  }

  async setName(newName) {
    this.myName = newName;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.myName;
  }
}
const name = new Name();
console.log(name.setName.constructor.name);
```

Comment: When you run this code you get an error.

Comment: just run this code on my pc and it returns "AsyncFunction"

Comment: cause if you have a transpilation step in between, async functions might get transpiled into functions returning promises.

Comment: @jonas-wilms, can you give me some clues about where I can read more about it?

Comment: inspect that iframe inside codesandbox, it contains your transpiled code.

Comment: Is the react code setup to transpile down to ES5?  That could be the culprit.

Comment: @Taplar even compiling to ES2015 would be sufficient. `async` wasn't introduced into the spec until ES2017

Comment: That seems the case Taplar, as Jonas said... I am trying to figure out how to solve it

Comment: @augustoamaral "how to solve it" is to not rely on it in the first place.

Comment: @patrick-roberts I will try a different approach so, anyway, thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Please just don't use `.constructor.name` to type-check anything. If a return value might be a promise, just normalize all return values into promises without checking them, i.e. `Promise.resolve(name.setName()).then(...)`.